# how to disable the instance-reset module in zaicopx repack plz?

Tags: azerothcore

can not disable the instance-reset module from zaicopx repack when set the instanceReset.Enable=false

i have tried to set:instanceReset.Enable=false\instanceReset.Enable=0\instanceReset.Enable=disable

and the module keeps enable

anyone knows how to disable it or remove it from zaicopx repack?

Comment: Dont use a repack, compile it yourself. Problem solved

Comment: Do not use repacks, here is why: https://www.mangosrumors.org/why-you-should-not-use-repacks-to-run-your-wow-server

Answer (score 2):

For your information, AzerothCore doesn't support repacks, so we can't help on issues with unofficial releases.

If the module used by the repack is `mod-instance-reset`, using `false` should work (see the [default config](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-instance-reset/blob/master/conf/instance-reset.conf.dist)). Did you restart your worldserver after changing the values?

You'd be better off asking the repack's author, or even better: using a [classic AzerothCore install](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/installation#azerothcore-classic-setup).